# How to lower the SOLR-score value of a result found using synonyms?

Tags: solr

The solr server has keywords (like school, window or blog) associated to ids.

The querys to the server are very basic ones like `window AND blog`.

The server also has a very large synonyms.txt, so if you search `world wide web` you will also get the results for `internet`.

Question: How do I lower the score value of a result found using the synonyms?

Example: I got the synonyms `world wide web` and `internet`. I define a document with the keyword `world wide web` and one with the keyword `internet`. 
Now I search for `internet`: Both documents will be found, but I want the one with the exact `internet` keyword ranking higher.

Answer (score 3):

You could make 2 fields. 1 with synonyms and one without. Give the one without synonyms a higher weight.

Comment: But the synonyms are stored in the global synonyms file for the server. Wouldn't it be a lot of overhead to save every synonmyn to every document?

Comment: We use `SynonymFilterFactory` .. it injects synonyms into the same field.. how is it possible to use synonym terms generated by `SynonymFilterFactory` to be stored in a separate field? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could (by using the synonym file), alter the query as to generate something like (assuming we start with the keyword `world wide web`):

```
("world wide web"^2.0 OR internet OR WWW)
```

Boosting the default form, and no the synonyms.

And when I say alter, I say that from your application (where the query is prepared for a solr request).